# Sorting list of tuples f#

Tags: list, sorting, f#, tuples

this should be really quick, I have a list of tuples like [("8585", 1);("9232",1);etc] where the second item corresponds to the number of ocurrences the item in "" makes.  I was wondering how could i arrange my list from the one that makes more ocurrences to the one that makes least.

f#!

Comment: What's your problem? What's keeping you from running it through a sort function?

Comment: Do you want an answer in any specific language?

Comment: I used List.sortby snd and it sorted from the one with least appearences to the one with most..I needed the other way around

Comment: sorry, i am using f#

Comment: Many sort implementations allow you to specify the order, usually through a boolean argument that takes `true` for ascending or `false` for descending. If not, you'll just have to reverse the list.

Comment: i tried using List.foldback but it didnt work. should i specify something because they are tuples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use sortBy:

```
let lst = [("8585", 1);("9232",3)]
List.sortBy (fun (_, y) -> -y) lst
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Gustavo implied, if it's numeric, you can negate it to reverse its order in sorting. That's what the unary operator `~-` is for.

Your peculiar choice of data, that is tuples of `'something * int`, let me suspect that you are counting the number of certain occurences, and for that `Seq.countBy` may help (sorry, no list equivalent).

```
// Your key, Some data 
[  "9232",   false
   "8585",   false
   "9232",   true 
   "9232",   true ]
|> Seq.countBy fst
|> Seq.sortBy (snd >> (~-))

// val it : seq<string * int> = seq [("9232", 3); ("8585", 1)]
```

That's sorted by the count (`snd` element of the tuple) of the key (`fst` element of the tuple) negated.

Answer (score 1):

F# does have List.sortByDescending, so you could have:

```
[("8585", 1);("9232",3)]
|> List.sortByDescending (fun (_,y) -> y)
```